# CFSocketCreate or constructor method missing. How do you create a CFSocket using Swift?

Tags: swift, ios8

Any method call to instantiate a CFSocket seem to be missing from the import CoreFoundation

```
import CoreFoundation

var socket:CFSocket = CFSocket()
```

The reference documentation doesn't show anything when swift only is selected:

```
Creating Sockets

4 Objective-C symbols hidden
```

How can I instantiate a CFSocket under Swift?

Comment: How would you do it in Objective-C?  If you can work that out then it should be similar in Swift.

Comment: I tried using a default ctor, or a call to CFSocketCreate(nil, 0, 0, 0, 0, nil, nil) but there seems no way to get Swift to instantiate the CFSocket directly without using a bridge to objc and writing the code in a .m file.

Comment: Is that how you'd do it under Objective-C?

Comment: The CFSocketCreateXXX() functions seem not to be available in Swift. Filing a bug report at Apple is probably the only thing you can do.

Comment: Thank you. I filed a radar @Apple: 17361010

Comment: I just checked this Swift based http server project: https://github.com/glock45/swifter he is using Darwin based socket in Swift code, why don't you choose that way?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's too old

Answer (score 1):

i had the same Problem. It is a CF struct not an Object so you have no a constructor.
You can use `CFSocketCreate`.

Some think like this:

```
  let socket : CFSocket = CFSocketCreate(_ allocator: CFAllocator!,
              _ protocolFamily: Int32,
              _ socketType: Int32,
              _ `protocol`: Int32,
              _ callBackTypes: CFOptionFlags,
              _ callout: CFSocketCallBack,
              _ context: UnsafePointer<CFSocketContext>)
```

[Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFSocketRef/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CFSocketCreate)

Comment: but it's still not very useful because how are you going to get a `CFSocketCallBack` in Swift?

Comment: Sorry i was not at may Workstation. Here a correct Version ipv4socket = CFSocketCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP, CFSocketRef.kCFSocketAcceptCallBack, (CFSocketCallBack).self&TCPServerAcceptCallBack) and TCPServerAcceptCallBack is a instant function in the same Class to handle new connections.

Comment: you can't turn a Swift function into a `CFunctionPointer`

Comment: Yes to day i find the same Problem. Now i will chance back to NSSocketPort until CFSocket is fixed

Answer (score 0):

replace callout with closure like below:

```
let socket = CFSocketCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault,
                          PF_INET, 
                          SOCK_STREAM, 
                          IPPROTO_TCP, 
                          2,
                          { (socket,_,_,_,_) in },
                          nil)
```